# Get PC specs with WMIC /APPEND

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
whoami > "%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt"
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" BIOS Get Manufacturer,Name /Format:table
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" Baseboard Get Product,Manufacturer /Format:table
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" CPU Get Name,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /Format:table
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" Memorychip Get Manufacturer,Capacity,Speed,PartNumber /Format:table
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" Diskdrive Get Model,Size /Format:table
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" Path Win32_VideoController get Caption,VideoModeDescription /Format:table
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" OS get Caption,OSArchitecture,Version /Format:table
WMIC /APPEND:"%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt" netuse get Name /Format:table 
pause
```

All works well, except the string with OS: only "Caption                              OSArchitecture         Version   " can be seen, but in CMD I can see that script shows

```
Caption                              OSArchitecture         Version
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  64-bit  10.0.17134
```

How to make script not to erase this string?

Comment: That doesn't happen here, the output is OK onscreen and in the file.

Comment: I tried to use OUTPUT, but only the last string saved (just replaced APPEND with OUTPUT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes WMIC is a little too smart for itself with its Unicode output. Running it all through `FIND` will convert it to the local codepage.

```
@echo off
SET "OUTFILE=%~dp0%computername%_%username%.txt"
IF EXIST "%OUTFILE%" (DEL "%OUTFILE%")

(
whoami
WMIC BIOS Get Manufacturer,Name /Format:table
WMIC Baseboard Get Product,Manufacturer /Format:table
WMIC CPU Get Name,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors /Format:table
WMIC Memorychip Get Manufacturer,Capacity,Speed,PartNumber /Format:table
WMIC Diskdrive Get Model,Size /Format:table
WMIC Path Win32_VideoController get Caption,VideoModeDescription /Format:table
WMIC OS get Caption,OSArchitecture,Version /Format:table
WMIC netuse get Name /Format:table
) | FIND /V "" >>"%OUTFILE%"
```